# The name [ControlName] missing in current context w/ Database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I am new to Visual Studio and am trying to hammer through some ASP.NET/C# Web Form Tutorials. In my code I am trying to make a database connection to our corp SQL Server.

Visual Studio 2013
SQL Server 2012

The tutorial I'm following recommends configuring the DB connection string in Web.config:

```
<!-- Johns Connection String to the DB -->
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=TheServerName;initial catalog=TheDatabaseName;user id=TheUserName;password=ThePassword;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The web-facing page is basic. I only want it to say whether I made the connection or not. Here is the CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace CPITraining
{
    public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionFromConfiguration =     WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"];
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new     SqlConnection(connectionFromConfiguration.ConnectionString))
        {
                try
                { 
                    dbConnection.Open();
                    ltConnectionMessage.Text = "Connection Successful.";
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    ltConnectionMessage.Text = "Connection failed: " + ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    dbConnection.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly, here's the webpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="Colors Example" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="CPITraining.TestForm" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltConnectionMessage" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltOutput" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I keep getting The name 'ltConnectionMessage' does not exist in the current context'.

Not sure how to get around this error. Thanks for any help.
John

Comment: Could you paste ltConnectionMessage definition from code behind file? are you able to access ltOutput from webpage?

Comment: would that be the ltConnectionMessage.Text = "Connection Successful."; type statements I posted?

Comment: no, TestForm is partial class. So, there will be another file (filename will be different but it will define TestForm class in it. Expand your solution view and you will see at the same level of this form file). That file will have control definitions. But are you able to access ltOutput?

Comment: thanks I'll check when I get home

Comment: Thanks for your help @sam, but I'll need to rewind. I read up on partial classes a bit. It seems the partial class lets you setup a single class function over multiple files, then the files compile into a single class when the project is built. While the tutorial I'm using teaches the SQL server connection code, the author, and the sample code, doesn't explain the partial class (or where the rest of the definition is). So for me, the tutorial is useless without the whole picture. I'll try to find something else. To your question about ltOutput - it does nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found three better tutorials that, together, provide a sound construction method for standing up a gridview in ASP.NET with C#. I am not sure whether it is appropriate to post the tutorials here. I don't want it to appear that I am withholding information, but I also dont want it to look like I am advertising for the tutorials. The tutorial focus also in no way relates to the subject of this thread.